# PHP - codeigniter - control date format

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter, date

I have a form using which users can edit their own birthdate, i save the birthdates in the DB in this format `15/24/1989` which is dd/mm/yyyy

how can i check that the form birthday post value is formatted as shown?

also what if i pass 12/00/hello ?

i think i need numerics only and in a range of date 01 > dd < 31 , 01 > mm < 12 , 1920 > yyyy < current_year –

Comment: it's fb standard :/ me too can't digest, need to tell it to mark zuchenbergggg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($this->input->post('date')));
```

To validate date in this format you should use this function.

```
function checkDateFormat($date) {
    if (preg_match('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/', $date)) {
        if(checkdate(substr($date, 3, 2), substr($date, 0, 2), substr($date, 6, 4)))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will check the date format, as well as check the actual date itself with the PHP `checkdate()` function.

```
checkDateFormat("10/10/2010"); // true
checkDateFormat("29/02/2008"); // true
checkDateFormat("29/02/2007"); // false
checkDateFormat("10/10/20101"); // false
checkDateFormat("ilikecookie"); // false
```

etc.

Comment: the same as the answer above, 15/24/1989

Comment: @Aaaaaaa y dont u use jquery date picker to limit ur user from entering invalid date

Comment: @Aaaaaaa please refer to the manual, if you pass a string that is a date it will parse it as date: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: js is ok but i'm talking about server side cause js is hackable

Comment: i tryed this code with no success i do this : if(!$birthday or !date("d/m/Y", strtotime($birthday)))

Comment: but it returns false always also if $birthday = "hey hey hey "

Comment: @Vlakarados i need to control not to format that, if user use the right format d/m/Y return true; else return error;  just this i need

Comment: @Aaaaaaa why would you need to force users to write it this way other than transforming it by yourself? Anyway, I've updated my answer with a regex for dates of this kind

Comment: uhmmmmm ... Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Comment: also what if i pass 12/00/hello ?

Comment: @Vlakarados i think i need numerics only and in a range of date 01 > dd < 31 , 01 > mm < 12 , 1920 > yyyy < current_year

Comment: @Aaaaaaa once again I have updated my answer, please try to do at least some research yourself before asking so many questions. It will check now if the date is valid

Comment: @Vlakarados thx man, but it's still returning me the error : preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '('

Comment: Please post full error code and your code you are trying to run

Comment: @Vlakarados if (preg_match("/^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$/", $birthday, $parts)){
        if(checkdate($parts[2],$parts[1],$parts[3])){
            $birthday_check = 1;
          }

    }

    if($birthday_check != 1){
    $error['error'] = 1;
    $error['birthday'] = 'Please use the right date format for field <strong>birthday</strong> (mm/dd/yyyy).';
    }

Comment: Why would you do that? use my function and run if(checkDateFormat($birthday)) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: @Vlakarados ok now i'm using that but still receiving same erro message :/

Comment: i think there is somenthing with separators ... can we chat? i can't cause i'm new here :/

Comment: Once again, I've updated the answer and tested this numerous times

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime(this->input->post('date'))
```